# Different labels from when email is addressed to me and when only copied to me

Tags: gmail, gmail-filters, gmail-labels

How can I create these two filters in Gmail?

Filter 1: I am on the To: list -> apply label 1

Filter 2: I am on the cc: list -> skip inbox, apply label 2

Answer (score 4):

**Filter 1**

In the "To" field type your email address.

**Filter 2**

In the "Has the Words" field use:

> cc:your_email@gmail.com

Comment: This configuration also Applies label 1 to my emails where I'm in "cc" but not in "to". Why?
filter-> to:(name@email.com)

Comment: It appears that "to" means "to or cc or bcc", I haven't found that documented anywhere but that certainly appears to be the behavior

Answer (score 4):

To get around the fact that "to" usually means "to or cc or bcc" try using the minus operator.  Adjust for BCC as needed.  With these rules I believe BCC will still land in your inbox but I did not test that condition.

**Filter 1**

```
Matches: to:(your_email@gmail.com) -cc:your_email@gmail.com -bcc:your_email@gmail.com
Do this: Skip Inbox, Apply label "your_label_name"
```

**Filter 2**

```
Matches: cc:your_email@gmail.com
Do this: Skip Inbox, Mark as read, Apply label "your_second_label_name"
```